# Is Spacy nlp(text) thread safe?

Tags: python, spacy

Is the following thread safe in spacy?

```
nlp = spacy.load('en')
nlp(text)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes. See this thread (no pun intended...) for more information: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/172

If possible, instead of multi-threading the call to `nlp`, consider calling `nlp.pipe` which is a multithreaded call to the spaCy pipeline.

```py
for doc in nlp.pipe(texts, n_threads=16, batch_size=10000):
    analyse_text(doc)
```

More info here: https://explosion.ai/blog/multithreading-with-cython